# Changing Java annotation parameter default

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I use a library that provides an annotation `@LibraryAnnotation` with a Boolean parameter `parameter`. The default is set to `true` by the authors of the library.

Unfortunately, in almost all my use cases, I prefer the annotation with `parameter = false`. To achieve the desired behavior, I use `@LibraryAnnotation(parameter=false)` instead of `@LibraryAnnotation` every time. This is error prone since one easily forgets to set the parameter.

I am wondering if there is a way to simplify things by changing the default value for the parameter of `@LibraryAnnotation` or by defining a custom annotation that behaves like `@LibraryAnnotation(parameter=false)`, but does not require setting a parameter.

(In this particular case, the library is lombok, but the question could be relevant for parametrized annotations provided by any library. **Update**: Lombok offers [default parameter configuration](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration) via a `lombok.config` file, but I am still interested in a general solution.)

Comment: Did you try to define your own annotation? This would be the way to go, I think ...

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own annotation and use that instead. Something like:

```
@LibraryAnnotation(parameter = false)
public @interface MyLibraryAnnotationFalse {
}
```

Comment: That sound great. Is there any way to handle the case when `@LibraryAnnotation` is not valid for target `ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE`?